# Do I need to Configure Access 2010 Services if I only use Access Services in SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, access-services

We will have Office 2016 installed on everyone's desktop so do I need to configure the Access Services 2010 along with "Access Services" for SharePoint 2016 ?

Bismarck

Comment: MS is deprecating Access Services https://redmondmag.com/articles/2017/04/04/access-services-for-sharepoint-online.aspx

Comment: That is for SharePoint Online.  We are using On-Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have customer, who are using office 2010 /Access 2010 and want to view / update or want to publish the 2010 database in SharePoint 2016 then you need Access 2010 service application. It is included for the backward compatibility.
[Also check this answer from Bill](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f60da73b-a009-44eb-b659-75a553cc03fe/access-services-2010-service-app-in-2016-preview?forum=SP2016)

If everyone on office 2016 and no old access dbs then you only need Access service.